# jQuery: Add additional array to serialized form data via ajax and access it with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm currently lookong for a proper way to get add additional data (especially an array) to serialized data from a form and access it via PHP later on. I tried a lot, but nothing really worked.

For Instance:

**HTML:**

```
    <form id='addUserForm'>
       <input type='text' name='firstname'>
    </form>
```

**JS/JQUERY:**

```
var testArr =  {
    one: "1", 
    two: "2",
    three: 3
};


var ser = $("#addUserForm").serializeArray();

ser.push({ newArr:testArr});

console.log(ser);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: ser,
});
```

I used serializeArray() and pushed a new array to the serializedArray.
When I console.log -> it works fine. But when I am trying to access it on PHP like:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

I get:

```
array(2) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(6) "123123"
  ["undefined"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

It says that it is "undefined", even though via console.log in JS, the push was succesful.

Also I tried to convert it to a JSON string, with `JSON.stringify(ser)` and `data: {ser:ser}` -> which works, but it is more than awkward to access it.

I want to access it on PHP with `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['testarr']` instead of `$_POST[0]['value']`.

**I hope it makes sense. So long story short: How can I add additional data / array to a serialized string and access it properly on PHP later on?**

Comment: What does $("#addUserForm") contain?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this. Replace:

```
ser.push({ newArr:testArr});
```

with this:

```
for (var prop in testArr) {
    ser.push({name: prop, value: testArr[prop]});
}
```

What we're doing here is creating an array of objects, each containing a name and value properties.